# How to protect private field in class with getter in java

Tags: java, getter

I have the following code.

```
public class GetterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car();

        StringBuilder wheel = car.getWheel();
        wheel.append("asd");

        System.out.println(car.getWheel());
    }
}

class Car {

    private StringBuilder wheel;

    public Car() {
        wheel = new StringBuilder("a");
    }

    public StringBuilder getWheel() {
        return wheel;
    }

    public void setWheel(StringBuilder wheel) {
        this.wheel = wheel;
    }

}
```

The problem here is even I have a getter it don't protect the variable and it is changed after using it. How to protect the variable better?

Comment: If you don't what it to be able to be changed in the way that you changed it, you would need to make it a String instead of a StringBuilder; but since you have it open in the setWheel method it would still be mutable by an outside program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StringBuilder` variable is not a good candidate for a getter. It would make more sense to have a getter that returns the current `String` value of that `StringBuilder`, since a `String` it immutable :

```
public String getWheel() {
    return wheel.toString();
}
```

The setter should also be changed, since the current impl allows the caller of the setter to mutate the StringBuilder that was passed to the setter, and thus mutate the member after the setter is called.

```
public void setWheel (String wheel)
{
    this.wheel = new StringBuilder (wheel);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to change StringBuidlder to String the question is in general purpose - you can imagine I have another regular Object but not StringBuilder

Comment: @naskobg13 In the general case the getter can return a copy of the member, so that the original member can't be mutated by the caller of the getter.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't return the `StringBuilder` but rather the value. This creates a new `String` which isn't connected to your backing `StringBuilder` anymore.

```
public String getWheel() {
    return wheel.toString();
}
```

However if you really want to return a `StringBuilder`, you can create a new one with the current one's data, essentially disconnecting both instances:

```
public StringBuilder getWheel() {
    return new StringBuilder(wheel.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the field's that you want to protect getter you can clone the field instead of returning the current field.

```
public void doSomething() {
    Car car = new Car();

    Wheel wheel = car.getWheel();
    wheel.getaVariable().append("asd");

    System.out.println(car.getWheel());
}

public class Car {
    private Wheel wheel;

    public Car() {
        wheel = new Wheel();
    }

    public Wheel getWheel() {
        Wheel output = null;
        try {
            output = wheel.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // Manage exception
        }
        return output;
    }

    public void setWheel(Wheel wheel) {
        this.wheel = wheel;
    }
}

public class Wheel implements Cloneable {
    private StringBuilder aVariable;

    public Wheel() {
        aVariable = new StringBuilder("a");
    }

    public StringBuilder getaVariable() {
        return aVariable;
    }

    public void setaVariable(StringBuilder aVariable) {
        this.aVariable = aVariable;
    }

    @Override
    protected Wheel clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Wheel clone = (Wheel) super.clone();
        clone.setaVariable(new StringBuilder(aVariable));
        return clone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return aVariable.toString();
    }
}
```